# Why does a constant in an integral only sometimes have an antiderivate

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

## Summary

Consider the following indefinite integrals:

**A)** $$\int (2 + 3) dx = 5\ + C$$
**B)** $$\int (2 + 3x) dx = 2x + \frac{3x^2}{2}\ + C$$

As you can see, simply appending $x$ after $3$ also affects $2$. This doesn't appear to be consistent to me. I can see how A is correct assuming that you pull the constants out of the integration. I can also see how B is correct assuming you don't pull the constant out of the integral.

### Question(s)

Why is the number $2$ treated differently between the two integrals? Or, as the title of the question implies: why aren't we finding the antiderivative of the number $2$ in A, but we *ARE* in B?

---

#### Edit: 4/18/2018

As commenters have explained, it turns out that [cymath](https://www.cymath.com/answer?q=integrate%20(2%2B3)) is incorrectly evaluating the integral (A) above. It should be...

$$\int (2 + 3) dx = 5x\ + C$$

...which shows consistency between A and B.

Comment: A isnt correct.  The derivative of right hand side is not integrand.

Comment: $\int{2}dx=2x+c$ not $2$.

Comment: A is $5x + C$, not just $5 + C$

Comment: Are you all telling me the internet is wrong? :P Check out the result in cymath https://www.cymath.com/answer?q=integrate%202%20%2B%203

Comment: Adding $x$ to the three makes it such that the two parts of the integral, $2$ and $3x$, have different rates of change. Thus, doing an operation regarding rates of change is going to yield two expressions with no like terms because of this difference.

Comment: @RyanShesler Thanks for the edit. I reverted A back to the incorrect result. Otherwise, the question becomes meaningless. I like the improved formatting though. :)

Comment: Yep, cymath gives the wrong answer here. It's not true that the integral of $2 + 3$ is $5 + C$.

Comment: Take the derivative of 5. This yields 0, as is for any constant. So the derivative of 5 cannot be 5, meaning the above integral is incorrect. Try using https://www.integral-calculator.com/ , its more reliable and can do more complex integrals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number $2$ isn't treated differently between the two antiderivatives.

Your first example $\int{2+3}dx$ can be rewritten as the following.
$$\int{2x^0+3x^0}dx$$
Applying the same rule you used in your second example, it is easier to see that this becomes $5x+C$.

Your second example is correct. This antiderivative has an extra term so it gets dealt with accordingly. That is, $\int{2+3x}dx=2x+\frac{3x^2}{2}+C$.

In summary, the constant will always have an antiderivative. Reading the comments as I finish typing this answer, it appears that Cymath is incorrect in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the first formula contains a mistake, and hence is putting you on the wrong track: actually

$$\int (2 + 3)\ dx = (2 + 3)x + C = 5x + C$$

**not** $(2 + 3) + C$, or $5 + C$. The way to remember this is that you can always pull a constant out of an integral:

$$\int k\ dx = k \int dx$$

and the integral of $dx$ is simply $x$, up to a constant shift, because effectively you are just adding up all the small increments of $x$, which is what $dx$ represents, beginning with some unspecified starting value upon which we commence said incrementation.

With this mistake fixed, you should be able to see now the connection between this case and the case where we have a linear function inside the integral.